# Using Command Prompt to access python

Tags: python, command-prompt

I want to do is create a new python script so that I can start coding in python.
I am new to using windows command prompt. How can I access and create a new python script using the command prompt window? I have tried using `cd (location of already made script)`. I have also just used `data\scripts` which is where the rest of the python scripts are located.

I have also attached a screenshot of what I attempted.

[image]

Comment: You don't typically use the command prompt to *create* a Python script. You use a text editor or IDE to create a Python script, and then you might *run* it from the command prompt.

Comment: you have to enter into python shell. If python is in your PATH, the  simply typing python will let you into the shell then you can write. other wise navigate to /bin/python and enter python

Comment: You will do yourself a massive favour not just working from the command prompt. Windows lacks a decent text editor on the command line, so you're better off starting with one of the many free alternatives, like VSCode or PyCharm community. Even a basic text editor like Notepad++ or even just Notepad is a better idea than the bare CLI. (And I'm assuming you're not on Linux because of your use of the phrase 'command prompt window')

Comment: All you really need is a decent text editor. The one I use let me customize it to run the script I'm editing and captures any output it produces — there are many that can do this.

Comment: Also note the paths on Windows use backslashes, so you would need to type `cd U:\data\scripts` at the command prompt to change to that subdirectory.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: We don't know whether you have a folder named U:\data\scripts or why you just mistyped the name, or if you are trying to access something which simply isn't installed on your system. Voting to close as lacking enough details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access this in the CMD, you just need to type:-

`cd data\scripts`

Then you will be in your directory.

If you just want shell access, type:-

`python`

in the interface.